# ActionBar overflow visibility on KitKat

Tags: android, android-actionbar

It seems that on KitKat the overflow button is always visible, regardless of the presence of a dedicated menu button on the device.

Is there a way to disable this behaviour?

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: Any method you find with be a hack. You're fighting against Google's direction for menus in Android: http://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/1sghyd/kitkatgoogle_wants_to_kill_the_menu_button_always